# How to use a list to label a BarChart

Tags: dataset, charts

I'm trying to add [labels](/questions/tagged/labels) to the `BarChart` I have generated from a `Dataset` however, I seem to be stuck on a couple of points.
Firstly given the below syntax, where am I supposed to add in the `BarChart` options?

```
test = Dataset[{
    <|"num" -> 0|>, <|"num" -> 0|>, <|"num" -> 1|>, <|"num" -> 2|>, <|
     "num" -> 0|>, <|"num" -> 0|>, <|"num" -> 1|>, <|"num" -> 2|>, <|
     "num" -> 2|>, <|"num" -> 1|>, <|"num" -> 2|>, <|"num" -> 3|>, <|
     "num" -> 3|>, <|"num" -> 5|>, <|"num" -> 4|>, <|"num" -> 5|>, <|
     "num" -> 0|>, <|"num" -> 5|>}];
test[Counts, #num &]
test[Counts /* BarChart, #num &]
```

Secondly, I know I can add in

```
...,ChartLabels->{"list","of","things"} ...
```

but I really want to pass the output of the `Counts` so that I can do it programatically for a number of different `Datasets`.

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a [Pure Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) with [`BarChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart.html) that takes the results of your query and has the options you want. Use [`Keys`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Keys.html) to get the chart labels from [`Counts`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Counts.html)

**Inline**

```
test[Counts /* (BarChart[#, ChartLabels -> Keys[#]] &), #num &]
```

**Defined**

```
myChart = BarChart[#, ChartLabels -> Keys[#]] &;
test[Counts /* myChart, #num &]
```

Both methods give

[image]

Hope this helps.

**Note:** You can also replace `Keys[#]` with `Automatic` since `BarChart` understands `Associations`.  In fact using `Automatic` is better if you have multiple levels.

```
test[Counts /* (BarChart[#, ChartLabels -> Automatic] &), #num &]
```

and

```
myChart = BarChart[#, ChartLabels -> Automatic] &;
test[Counts /* myChart, #num &]
```

Comment: @infinityplusb See update with [`Keys`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Keys.html).

Comment: Ah, I tried the `Keys` thing, but without the `#`
Thanks for the link too, that should make some good reading. :)